# Is there an Android equivalent of the iOS didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Tags: android, memory-management

I want to know when is a good time to release resources on Android.  I'd like to keep the memory in use for as long as possible because reloading things does impair the user experience.

The resources I'm talking about here are images, mostly.

Comment: "Release resources"?  You should *ALWAYS* release every "resource" like a socket or a file handle *AS SOON* as possible.  And, since you're programming in Java, you don't have to worry about "free()" or "delete[]"ing objects.  Q: So what exactly *are* you asking about?

Comment: BTW: These linsk might be helpful: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html and http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it's [onLowMemory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onLowMemory%28%29) function you need to overwrite.

Comment: I ended up using Activity.OnLowMemory().